# Java Programming Question - Hex Editor Assignment

Tags: java, iterator, hex

I'm working on a Hex Editor for a school assignment. Two things it should be able to do is:

**1.) From a position the user indicates, print the next 5 bytes from that position.**

**2.) From a position the user indicates, print the 5 bytes before from that position.**

I'm supposed to do this using an iterator, and I'm not entirely sure how to because Iterator only has a next method. I've done it without an iterator first:

```
System.out.print("Enter byte positon to navigate to: ");
        long pos = in.nextLong();
        in.nextLine();
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < file.length()) {
            raf.seek(pos);
            System.out.println("The 5 bytes starting from that position are");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                byte b = raf.readByte();
                System.out.print(((b >= 0 && b <= 15)?"0":"") + Integer.toHexString((int)b & 0x00FF) + " ");
                if (++pos == file.length())
                    break;
            }
```

Where should I start in order to convert this to use an iterator?

Also, for the 5 bytes before, should I decrement the position the user specifies and and then iterate 5 bytes forward?

Comment: See [ListIterator](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/06/listiterator-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: as far as making the iterator is concerned, what would the listiterator be of? Basically, I have pos as a long int, but can i do something like pos.listIterator() or would I be dereferencing it?